# blur on an image

Tags: jquery

Please look at this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("td.setting").click(function () {
        text = jQuery(this).text();
        jQuery(this).replaceWith("<input class='inputSetting' type='text' value=" + text + "><img class=\"accept\" src='images/accept.png'>");
        console.log(text);
    });
    jQuery("img.accept").bind('click', function () {
        console.log("blur");
    });
});
```

When I press on the `td`. The input box appears. But when I clicked on the accept `img` nothing happens. There should be a message on my console "blur" but nothing happens.

I also tried:

```
jQuery("img.accept").click(function () {
    console.log("blur");
});
```

But this also doesn't work.

Comment: Does console.log even work? What about trying it with an alert()?

Comment: console.log works fine because it shows me the text of the td.setting when i click on it.

Comment: Does the <img> have a class called accept assigned to it and what about $("img.accept").click(...);

Comment: This is how it looks if firebug: <img class="accept" src="images/accept.png" alt="accept button"/>
I also tried jQuery("img.accept").click(...);  but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try using [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live#typefn) instead of bind for the image.

Comment: it really works with         jQuery("span.accept").live('click',function(){
          console.log("blur");
});